# Allow access to specific Codeigniter controller using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, .htaccess

I am running an 'intranet' online using codeigniter as a framework and have Denied all except one IP from accessing the directory in my .htaccess file.

I want to open just ONE directory / controller to the world

My current .htaccess file is this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

Ideally, I want to allow public to access the www.website.com/FOLDER/ directory only.

I'm certain this is fairly simple, but Codeigniter works on controllers NOT subdirectories.

Hoping you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the IP address in the constructor of your controller so that the world cant access the controllers which you do not want to be public. :)

Rough code:

```
$var=get ip address
if($var!= [ip address here])
{
redirect( [to someother page] );
}
```

Comment: But I want all controllers BAR this one to be restricted.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to use the htaccess file to allow from a certain subfolder rather than hardcode it in the php controller. I currently 'Allow from' a large array in the .htaccess file and it is the primary source of 'Allow' truth - and I dont want to mix up the logic inside an individual controller

Comment: You can extend **[CI_Controller](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)** as **My_Controller** and put @K Abhishek code inside **__construct** method. This way it will be available to your whole CodeIgniter application.